# Does Spring create new thread per request in rest controllers?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I wanted to learn non blocking REST, but first I wrote blocking controller for comparison. To my surprise Spring doesn't block incoming requests.

Simple blocking service:

```
@Service
public class BlockingService {

    public String blocking() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ign) {}
        return "Blocking response";
    }
}
```

Simple REST controller:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class BlockingRestController {

    private final BlockingService blockingService;

    @Autowired
    public BlockingRestController(BlockingService blockingService) {
        this.blockingService = blockingService;
    }

    @GetMapping("blocking")
    public String blocking() {
        log.info("Starting blocking request processing...");
        return blockingService.blocking();
    }
}
```

And I was thinking that when I send 4 requests using curl from 4 separated terminals I get:

```
1. Starting blocking request processing... (console where spring is running)
2. (4 terminals waiting)
3. "Blocking response" (in 1st terminal)
4. Starting blocking request processing... (console where spring is running)
5. (3 terminals waiting)
6. "Blocking response" (in 2nd terminal)
And so on...
```

But to my surprise I got:

```
1. Starting blocking request processing... (console where spring is running)
2. Starting blocking request processing... (console where spring is running)
3. Starting blocking request processing... (console where spring is running)
4. Starting blocking request processing... (console where spring is running)
5. "Blocking response" (in 1st terminal)
6. "Blocking response" (in 2nd terminal)
7. "Blocking response" (in 3rd terminal)
8. "Blocking response" (in 4th terminal)
```

Why first request doesn't block processing requests? Yet I don't create new threads and I don't process anything asynchronous?

Why do I ask about it? Because I want to learn how to use `DeferredResult`, but now I don't see a need.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's blocking in the sense that it blocks **one** thread: the thread taken out of the pool of threads by the servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc., **not** Spring) to handle your request. Fortunately, many threads are used concurrently to handle requests, otherwise the performance of any Java web application would be dramatic.

If you have, let's say, 500 concurrent requests all taking 1 minute to complete, and the pool of threads has 300 threads, then 200 requests will be queued, waiting for one of the threads to become available.

Comment: By reading the Tomcat documentation. Googling for "tomcat thread pool" should lead you to it: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/executor.html

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely NO since NIO!!!
Spring Web runs in a web container Tomcat or Netty, it is tomcat or Netty's work to create thread, not spring mvc or spring webflux.
If you use tomcat in a BIO model, it is definitely new thread per request.
Netty is of course NIO, tomcat supports NIO and APR, both are non-blocking,
Spring boot webmvc tomcat is default NIO, no need to worry about creating to many threads since nio.

[Tomcat 8 NIO,how it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576591/tomcat-8-nio-how-it-works)