# Tomcat 8 NIO,how it works?

Tags: java, tomcat8

I have created simple Spring Boot MVC application and noticed (using `JVisualVM`) that all my threads have prefix nio. That mean that Tomcat use `java.nio` package. We can add the following params to Tomcat configuration : `maxThreads,maxConnections`. As I know that mean:
For example we have `maxThreads` = 2 , `maxConnections` = 10000, then Selector of first thread (from `java.nio`) can handle `10000` concurrent requests, but execute each sequentially according to `selectorKeys` and the same behavior for the second thread.

Does it work in this way , if yes how do you usually choose the best option for `maxConnections`

Thank in advance

(BTW I use Tomcat 8 )

Comment: Can you clarify more what you mean with "choosing best option for maxConnections"?

Comment: I mean if you able to set 1000 or 2000 , what would you choose and why

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The maximum number of client connections is `acceptCount` + `maxConnections`. Too low and requests may be rejected unnecessarily. Too high and clients may be starved if throughput can't keep up.

**`acceptCount:`** - 100 by default - This is used as the `backlog` parameter for [`ServerSocket.bind`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#bind-java.net.SocketAddress-int-). The OS's TCP stack will queue at most `acceptCount` pending socket connections. This occurs before Tomcat starts processing the connection.

**`maxConnections:`** - 10,000 by default - The maximum number of connections that Tomcat allows to be in progress internally.

**`maxThreads:`** - 200 by default under NIO and NIO2 - Maximum number of concurrent request processing threads.

The goal is to optimize service availability and performance and utilize resources efficiently. The settings will depend on the latency and load distribution of your request processors.

There are many different approaches to capacity planning depending on the goals. A simple option is to increase `maxThreads` to the point where the server wouldn't be able to safely process any additional requests within a reasonable period of time. At this point of saturation, accepting more connections would be inadvisable since it would take too long to clear them out. So consider how much CPU time and RAM each processing thread requires and how many can safely run at the same time.

Comment: From docs maxConnections = 10000, maxThreads =200 by default
Maybe I don't understand, if maxConnections = 1000 so each tomcat thread can handle 1000 connections or all tomcat threads can handle 1000 connections together?

Comment: The maximum number of pending connections is `acceptCount`. The maximum number of *active* connections is `maxConnections`.

Comment: @AlmasAbdrazak Each request processing thread handles one request at a time, serially. When a thread is done with a request, it picks up another pending request from the queue. `maxConnections` is the number of socket connections that are active and monitored at any given time. (This is entirely different from the number of NIO threads handling IO events on the sockets.)

Answer (score 3):

> For example we have `maxThreads = 2, maxConnections = 10000`, then Selector of first thread (from java.nio) can handle 10000 concurrent requests, but execute each sequentially according to selectorKeys and the same behavior for the second thread.

No. They can handle 10,000 *between them*, in this case 5,000 each, sequentially. The maximum is global, not per-thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you've asked is answered here:
[Tomcat - maxThreads vs maxConnections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678661/tomcat-maxthreads-vs-maxconnections)

I believe it really depends on the nature of your application/service. It's best to do stress test the system and find the optimal values. Too many threads in a IO heavy application might cause significant delays because of high number of context switches.

Comment: Thank for response, but the main question, Am I right about how NIO threads work in Tomcat?

Comment: I believe it's answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678661/tomcat-maxthreads-vs-maxconnections